# MouseWheel event args for calculating the ScrollTop Value

Tags: html, mousewheel

I have use the following code snippet and also I have hide the vertical scroll bar by applying css(overflow-y :hidden).

```
<div class="gridheadercontainer" style="width: 300px;height: 300px;overflow: scroll; overflow-y:hidden; ">
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text

        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text

        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text

        <!-- <table class="table" cellspacing="0">
                 <colgroup>
                     <col style="width: 150px;">
                     <col style="width: 150px;">
                     <col style="width: 150px;">
                     <col style="width: 150px;">
                     <col style="width: 150px;">
                 </colgroup>
                 <thead>
                     <tr class="columnheader" style="cursor: pointer;">
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Task name</div></th>
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Start time</div></th>
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">End time</div></th>
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Duration</div></th>
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Status</div></th>
                         <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv"></div></th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody class="hide"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
             </table>-->
    </div>
```

How to calculate the scrollTop value for the div from the mouse wheel event action.

Answer (score 0):

### **FIXXXXXXXXED ITTTTTTT**

---

### [Whatr the odds, right?  Check out this beautiful violin.](http://jsfiddle.net/LX42E/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="pos">SCROLL POSITION</h1>

<div class="gridheadercontainer">
    <div id="theDiv">text text text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pos {
    right: 50px;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
}
#theDiv {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.gridheadercontainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-all;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var position = document.getElementById('pos');
var theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
theDiv.onscroll = function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    position.innerHTML = theDiv.scrollLeft + ' x ' + theDiv.scrollTop;
    e.stopPropagation();
};
```

There we go.  Corrected and perfect.

I made sure to demonstrate you wouldn't get the scroll position outside of the div too.

Enjoy.

EDITED:  Perfected for real this time, with horizontal scroll polling enabled

Comment: thank you for your update, as i mentioned in my question i have use the overflow-y hidden in this case onscroll event did not invoked

Comment: FIXED IT LOL GET @ MEEEEEEEE I'm gonna update the answer for ya.  It works the way you need it now hahaha I love it.